# Report Builder 3.0 Line chart - only show dots

Tags: sql, charts, report, reportbuilder3.0

Report Builder 3.0 Line chart - only show dots

I'am building a report with Report Builder 3.0.
Using a line chart. Unfortunately it only show dots.
The data doesn't contain null value's.

This is how the data looks like:

```
Application ResultSec   TestDate
Word        33          2013-11-25 12:09:25.000
Excel       15          2013-11-25 12:09:50.000
Outlook     11          2013-11-25 12:10:12.000
Word        32          2013-11-25 12:10:54.000
Excel       14          2013-11-25 12:11:18.000
Outlook     11          2013-11-25 12:11:39.000
```

This is how the chart looks like:
[image: Line chart only shows dot]

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You may select the dot and right click,then will prompt a menu,enable "show data label". Then you get it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm not looking for the data label (that's just a property) but for the line between the data points. All the points should be connected through a line. 

Also your sugestion is not working when I want to show the data labels.

Comment: Did you use line chart with Type definition of "Line,Plain"?

Comment: your chart seems to be the "Scatter, Plain"

Comment: It's a line chart with data dots. I have the same problem with a normal line chart

Comment: So please update your RDL file, you may capture the part of it for line chart

Comment: What do you mean exactly?